# Texmaker. Is it possible to compile not focused file?

Tags: compilation, focus, latex, pdflatex, texmaker

Does anybody know if it is possible to compile the file that is not being focused in texmaker?

I have a report separated into many .tex files and everyone of them included in Main.tex. In order to compile the report, I need to focus Main.tex file and then click the PdfLatex command. I would like to just click PdfLatex command and always compile Main.tex independently of what is being hovered. Does anybody know if this is doable?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Options -> Define Current Document as Master

These way when you use latex commands it is applied to master document.

[image: Current Document As Master]

Comment: This worked! Damn, it was so easy and I was trying more difficult things.